# Water Shut off Valve not turning back on

Tags: water, valve, shutoff

My condo unit's main cold water shutoff valve is not turning back on.

Our building had some water maintenance yesterday and the we turned off both hot and cold water shutoff valves inside our unit. After the maintenance was done, hot water shutoff valve turned on with ease. The cold water shutoff valve is not moving. It seems stuck in that position.

In the picture, the smaller valve is for hot water, the larger one is for cold water.

What is causing this issue and how can we fix this?

[image]

Comment: Be sure you are turning it the correct direction. Water pressure against the plug may make it difficult to operate.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The valve wiggles with ease a bit but will not rotate all the way. So we need to forcefully turn it on?

Comment: Did it take force to turn it off? It will probably take similar force to turn it on, possibly _more_ force. That looks to be metal piping under all the paint spray, you're not likely to break it by putting a bit of oomph into it

Comment: @Rob yes.  I turn my main water off when I go on vacation.  When I come back and turn it back on sometimes I need plyers